# GSM/GPRS & GPS Expansion

Tags: pi-2, gps, gsm

I bought a GSM/GPRS and GPS expansion, but it seem it lacked details.

http://www.open-electronics.org/a-gsmgprs-gps-expansion-shield-for-raspberry-pi/

1. The voltage was not specified, so I assumed one of the USB output can serve as the VCC (~5V).
2. The number of pins on the Raspberry Pi 2 does not match the pins of the shield. Any body know which pi pin should match the expansion pin?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find other info here:
http://www.open-electronics.org/tag/ft1075/

The shield can work with RPI 1/2/3 withour problem. Use a 26 connector to maintain compatibility.

You have to add power (12V >1A) from PWR connector. You can power the RPI closing the jumper J5V.

The pin out in the schematics is for RPI
http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/workshop/circuitnotes/raspberry_pi_circuit_note_fig2a.jpg

Answer (score 3):

The circuit quite clearly shows that it runs off 5V. It also appears to have provision for external power.

The link is quite old (it was obviously designed for a Model B) and the Pi has changed since. The 26 pin header should fit over the 1st 26 pins of the Pi2, although the later Pi changed the physical position of the pins (by a small amount) so it won't fit neatly on top.

It will probably work, although any software may be out of date.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any suggested expansion with Gsm and Gps to use?